# Can't compile code Error: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently having multiple errors in the code when I am trying to compile the code and I can't work out where I have gone wrong.

The errors I'm getting are in:

```
C:\Users\Jamie\AndroidStudioProjects\lifeWithASD\app\build\intermediates\manifests\
full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(18, 28) No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jamie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I am not sure why I would be getting these errors on compile as I don't know what the `@string/app name` is referring to in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you open your `AndroidManifest.xml`, from the opening at line 14, and the close at line 24, you need to make sure that you have a property called `android:label="@string/app_name"` if you do have that, then you need to open `strings.xml` inside of `AppPath/res/values` and create a String resource called app_name.

The second part of the error is the same issue.

To add a string into the xml file:

```
<string name="app_name">YourApplicationNameHere</string>
```

Comment: I am now getting an issue with linking a button to a new page:

  public void Parents(View v) {
        Button button=(Button) v;
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ParentPage.class));
    }

I can't work out if this code will link to a new activity page or not

Comment: If it fixed the error, then select it as the correct answer. That way, anyone who comes upon this question knows that it fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jamax91x Why are you instantiating the button inside of the click listener?

Comment: I just followed a youtube tutorial and that's what the person did at the time. I'm a novice with using android studio. I don't know how to correct this.

The XML code for the button:

 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Parents_page"
        android:id="@+id/ParentHome"
        android:onClick="Parents"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ChildHomepage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/MainActivity"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp" />

Comment: If all you do is instantiate the button, then you dont need that line of code. For your issue with starting other activities, check this link out: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the link out